# Customize Visual Studio defined value and Function name foreground color

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know how to change the color for defined value (eg: #define MyValue 1) and the function name.

For example on this video:

http://ddkwizard.assarbad.net/demo/

NTSTATUS is colored with blue whilst
NT_SUCCESS is colored with pink
DRIVER_ENTRY is colored with red

Please share if anyone knows how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can change the color from Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors > Text Editor > Display items, however there is no items such as "Function name" or "constant" which allow me to customize the color for them, for example like here: http://visualddk.sysprogs.org/screenshots/dbg1.gif

NTSTATUS foreground color is light purple (default is black);
IoCreateDevice foreground color is light brown (default is black);
PDEVICE_OBJECT foreground color is blue (default is black);

I'm thinking there is VS addin that can achieve this but still cannot find it.

Anyone has any thought?

Thanks.

**[SOLVED]**

Hello,

Thanks for Oliver Schneider from assarbad.net for providing me the answer.

Below is his reply:

> Hi,
>
> the solution is easy, you purchase Visual Assist X from Whole Tomato Software.
>   You will notice the price is relatively high, but once bought you only pay the maintenance and this program is worth every cent. Try it, if you don't believe me. I also think it is ideal for driver writers.
>
> // Oliver

Answer (score 0):

I can change the colors of the text in the Tools Menu and then select options, and click on Fonts & Colors

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio 2010 you can install [Highlighterr](http://highlighterr.codeplex.com/) which adds the following items to Display Items list:

- Highlighterr Reference
- Highlighterr Enum
- Highlighterr Function
- Highlighterr Macro
- Highlighterr Something
- Highlighterr Type
- Highlighterr Typedef